# Как через свой модуль изменить системные файлы опенкарта?

Tags: opencart, ocstore, модули

я хочу через свой модуль изменить системные файлы опенкарта например `(system/library/cart.php)` и `(catalog/model/catalog/product.php)` если установлен `vqmod` обратиться к `vqmod-у`
хочу сделать пользователям модуля максимальную удобство что бы они руками не меняли системные файлы

Comment: У Вас в чем именно сложность? В первой версии ОС используется vqmod, во второй ocmod. Большую часть файлов можно изменять с помощью модификаторов.

Comment: вопрос очень размытый.

Comment: согласен можно закрыть топик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [эта](http://s-engineer.ru/sozdaem-modul-v-opencart-2-x-ocmod/) статья может вам помочь при создании ocMod-расширения, если понимаете принцип.